# One script for updating two UI texts

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have multiple scores that I want to show on the screen, and also I want to create a text colour (range 0 to 100 will show red to green).

This is my script that I added the prefab (2 UI text):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class scoring: MonoBehaviour
{
    Text text;
    Text StatText2;

    public static int scoringValue = 80;
    public static int scoringValue2 = 10;

    float scoreDouble = scoringValue/100f;
    float scoreDouble2 = scoringValue2/100f;

    Color maxColor = new Color32(21, 193, 25, 255);
    Color minColor = new Color32(229, 85, 85, 255);

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
         text = GetComponent<Text>();

         StatText2 = GetComponent<Text>(); 
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        text.text =scoringValue.ToString();
        StatText2.text = scoringValue2.ToString();

         text.GetComponent<Text>().color = Color.Lerp(minColor, maxColor, scoreDouble);
         StatText2.GetComponent<Text>().color = Color.Lerp(minColor, maxColor, scoreDouble2);
         //Debug.Log(scoreDouble);  
    }
}
```

The result is `10` for both text box.

How can I display for each values?

Comment: `GetComponent<Text>();` returns the *first* component of type `Text`, so you are assigning both `Text` members the same value. You should either use `GetComponents<Text>` and assign the first and second element of that array, or use the inspector to assign which member refers to which text

Comment: Just make both fields `[SerializeField]` and reference both components via the Inspector and get completely rid of `GetComponent`. Note that also both `text.GetComponent<Text>()` and `StatText2.GetComponent<Text>` are completely redundant ... you either already have the reference or get an exception. In general never use `GetComponent` in `Update`

Comment: Are you sure both public text components don't refer to the same object?

Comment: @user14492 see UnholySheep's comment ... the fields are not `public` btw but assigned via `GetComponent<Text>` ;)

Comment: In that case they are referencing the same object... do what @derHugo says to assign them properly.

Comment: By the way, your `scoreDouble` values are not being updated to reflect the new score.

Comment: Thank you everyone for involving my question. @UnholySheep I didn't know we have getComponents option as well. Can you help me to point how can I use an array between two text object?

Comment: Hi @UnholySheep I solved problem with inspector. If you put in answer I would like to upvote. Thanks